# tsql : Access query to TSQL union update conversion correct?

Tags: t-sql, union

I have a query in access which i need to convert to a stored proc in sql server 2005.
the query in access is as follows:

```
UPDATE 
tblitem, 
tblFileSignature 
SET 
tblitem.strFileProcesstype = [tblFileSignature].[STRFILEPROCESSTYPE], tblitem.strFileSignatureType = [tblFileSignature].[strfilesignaturetype]
WHERE 
(((tblitem.strFileSignatureType) Is Null) AND 
((tblitem.strFileExclude)="n") AND 
((InStr([tblitem].[strfilesignature],[tblFileSignature].[strsignature]))=1) AND ((tblitem.uidItemType)=1 Or (tblitem.uidItemType)=5) AND 
((tblitem.uidCollection)=[forms]![frmSetup]![txtInputCol]) AND ((tblitem.strFileSignature) Not Like "d0c*") AND 
((tblFileSignature.strFileProcessType) Not Like "ZIP"));
```

in tsql.. would this be the same?

```
update tblItem 
set 
i.strFileProcesstype = f.strFileProcesstype,
i.strFileSignatureType = f.strfilesignaturetype 

from tblItem as I UNION tblFileSignature as F 

WHERE (((i.strFileSignatureType) Is Null) AND 
((i.strFileExclude)="n") AND 
((i.[strfilesignature] like F.strsignature)) AND 
((i.uidItemType)=1 Or 
(i.uidItemType)=5) AND 
((i.uidCollection)=@inputcolumn AND 
((i.strFileSignature) Not Like 'd0c%') AND 
((F.strFileProcessType) Not Like 'ZIP'));
```

thanks in advance

UPDATE:

so i'm going with the following.  if i uncomment the declare and select clause and just execute from the declare down, it runs, if i comment the declare and select parts, it says error near ';'.

```
UPDATE I  
SET 
    I.strFileProcesstype = F.STRFILEPROCESSTYPE, 
    I.strFileSignatureType = F.strfilesignaturetype
--declare @uidcollectionID int
--select I.strFileSignatureType
from 
tblItem I
    inner join tblFileSignature F
on 
I.strfilesignature = left(F.strsignature,len(I.strfilesignature))

WHERE I.strFileSignatureType Is Null 
    AND I.strFileExclude='n' 
    AND I.uidItemType in (1,5) 
    AND I.uidCollection = @uidCollectionID
    AND left(I.strFileSignature,3) <> 'd0c' 
    AND F.strFileProcessType <> 'ZIP';
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close to what you need. May need to work on the join condition, but I think my conversion from INSTR will do it.

```
UPDATE i
    SET strFileProcesstype = fs.STRFILEPROCESSTYPE, 
        strFileSignatureType = fs.strfilesignaturetype
    FROM tblitem i
        INNER JOIN tblFileSignature fs
            ON i.strfilesignature = LEFT(fs.strsignature, LEN(i.strfilesignature))
    WHERE i.strFileSignatureType IS Null 
        AND i.strFileExclude='n' 
        AND i.uidItemType IN (1,5)
        AND i.uidCollection = @inputcolumn 
        AND LEFT(i.strFileSignature,3) <> 'd0c' 
        AND fs.strFileProcessType <> 'ZIP';
```

Comment: i keep getting an error saying 'Incorrect syntax near 'ZIP'.
'

Comment: Hard to diagnose remotely. I think my syntax is all good. Does it make any difference if you drop the semi-colon?

Comment: that is without the semi-colon..if i add the semi-colon, it says incorrect syntax near ';'

Comment: if i add declare @inputcolumn select * to the from clause and highlight the rest..  it tells me the multi-part identifier i.strFileSignaturetype" could not be bound... same with strFileExclude,uidItemtype, and the rest of the items in the where clause.

Comment: if i do a select without the where clause, the select adjustment executes fine

Comment: @Phil: Curiosity will kill the cat. :-) What did you have to change to make it work? I'll edit my answer with any corrections needed for posterity's sake.

Comment: of course, once i removed the select clause to revert back to the update, it quit working..

Comment: @Phil: Assuming this gave you what you needed, could you please "accept" this answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**You should change the**

- `Double Quotes` to `Single Quotes`
- `*` to `%`
- Replace the `InStr` with `LIKE`

Other than that, it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

No, you'd use a JOIN, not a UNION.

You can either make it a CROSS JOIN, and continue to apply the join conditions in the WHERE clause, or you can make it an inner join:

```
from tblItem as I INNER JOIN tblFileSignature as F 
ON ((InStr(i.[strfilesignature],F.[strsignature]))=1)
```

And remove that condition from the WHERE clause (Lieven's answer also applies).